# Nested linear mixed effects model with time interaction

Tags: mixed-model, modeling

I am dealing with a fairly complex model in my current analysis and I think that I am not able to model it correctly. My data come from a database in which 40 subjects `pig` are divided into two groups `high.low` and subsequently in three more called `a.b.c`. Basically we have two levels of power delivered in three different ways. These groups are also studied over time. My goal is to understand if:

1) The groups are different, for example: is low power B different than high power B?

2) Are the groups evolving differently over time?

My model:

```
m1 <- lme(dependent_variable ~ hour * high.low/a.b.c, random = ~1|pig, data = dataframe)
```

Do you think this is a correct way of modeling the problem?

Comment: to clarify, each individual `pig` is treated with a single level each (i.e., a single combination) of `high.low` and `a.b.c`?

Comment: Exactly, each pig receives a single combination, meaning it will be for example high power A or , for example, low power C

Answer (score 1):

You can run then compare the following models:

```
m0 <- lme(dependent_variable ~ hour, random = ~1|pig, data = dataframe)
m1 <- lme(dependent_variable ~ hour + high.low/a.b.c, random = ~1|pig, data = dataframe)
m2 <- lme(dependent_variable ~ hour * high.low/a.b.c, random = ~1|pig, data = dataframe)
```

You can use a combination of likelihood ratio tests and information criteria for comparison.

If your comparisons unambiguously lead to:

- `m2`: at least one of the groups evolves differently from the others over time, this simultaneously answers question 1
- `m1`: the groups are different from each other but insufficient evidence to distinguish their evolution from each other
- `m0`: only growth over time is relevant, insufficient evidence to tell the groups apart

There is also a baseline no predictor model as an alternative to any of the three models above.